# What are the processes involved in recording electricity as a tradeable token on ethereum?

Tags: tokens

How can you record the generation of electricity onto ethereum as a tradeable token. Assuming that provenance is not an issue and a raspberry pi is used as a node to record electricity generation, would an API be required to for the raspberry pi to write and read from the blockchain? If so, are there any readily available API templates for ethereum that could be used in such a case?

Comment: It might be easier to address the question if the context is changed to IOT. What hardware/software/protocols would be required to get an IOT sensor to register data to ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a full answer (can't comment just yet), but Brainbot_Technologies has a great video on exactly this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6-rf68taTs